# Broad application applies to longstanding software capability

Tags: prior-art-request, prior-art, novelty

In reference to the patent: [US20150058243](https://www.google.com/patents/US20150058243)

This application is overly broad and would presume to cover long standing job search and matching capabilities used by large providers such as Monster.com; hired.com; indeed.com; and hotjobs.com.  The application should be denied because it would conflict with prior art technologies that were developed over 20 years ago and still in use by the general public and private industry.

This application should be limited to only a proprietary search algorithm, such as military occupation translation or a specific search optimization algorithm.  Still, these algorithms should be narrowly defined, unique, and proprietary because similar algorithms have been in use for decades and commonly used by the general public.

Answer (score 0):

If you have specific prior art that you have researched I do believe you may contact the attorney/agent of record. BTW this Case Docketed to Examiner in GAU 1-22-2016.

Quote:
"This means the application has been reviewed by the legal instruments examiner and all the papers have been entered into the Image File Wrapper for the examination by an examiner in the General Art Unit . The next thing that happens is the examination by the examiner who will issue an Office Action to either issue or deny or return the patent application for further information."

Contact the attorney/agent of record which are listed on the Public PAIR site with phone numbers.  They have the duty to inform the patent office of new art that comes to light:

http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair

JAMES C. WRAY,
1497 CHAIN BRIDGE ROAD,
SUITE 204,
MCLEAN VA 22101

703-442-4800

Comment: Rather send it in as a TPO (third party observation) to the USPTO directly. Thats ... safer.

Comment: @DonQuiKong If that is an accepted procedure, I would write it up as a separate answer.